# In Android, How to get image without saving image file

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

thank you for your appreciation in advance.

I am coding in next contidion.
`a. use internal camera app(I use Intent and other app to take pickture).`
`b. get image without saving into file.`

In my app, user take pickture of a credit card and send to server. Credit card image file is not necessary and saving image into file is not good for security.

Is it possible?

If it is impossible, is there anything else?

a. opening jpg file, editing all pixel into black
 b. use https://github.com/Morxander/ZeroFill

Whitch method is properable?

Comment: you can save it in temp file then when you are finished with sending to server delete it.

Comment: @SohailZahid thank you for your help!! How can I save in temp file?

Comment: @Sohail Zahid thank you for your help!! How can I save in temp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is `NO`.
You can't get an photo from default camera app without saving it into image.
What you can do is use Camera API to take photo inside your app, not using 3rd party default system photo app.

Comment: thank you! I know that I must use Camera API or wipe image file.

Answer (score 1):

Look here full [**Source.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)

Request this permission on the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On your `Activity`, start by defining this:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private ImageView mImageView;
```

Then fire this `Intent` in an `onClick`:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException");
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

Add the following support method:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Then receive the result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What made it work is the `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath))`, which is different from the code from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). The original code gave me a `FileNotFoundException`.